Disappearing buttons in the Unity WebGL build
I have 2 buttons to set the control scheme in my game and a script that fades the active scheme button. It works fine in the inspector, but after building on WebGL buttons disappear when I try to change their color.
ButtonsFade script: https://gist.github.com/Dankisey/7a0c16ce5e10b152da0d876cc0be3304
CustomButton script: https://gist.github.com/Dankisey/f6defadfc26f236b1155654690b332b5

I'd recommend avoiding to multiply colours as WebGL can handle colour values differently than other environments (editor). public void Fade() => _image.color *= _fadedColor; I'm not sure this is the answer but it's the only thing I see now.

@Thinkr yeah, that was the problem. _startColor = _image.color; was a problem too

You're welcome! ;)

Many thanks again to @Thinkr. The mistake was trying to do mathematical operations on Image.color and reading the color value from the Image component was also a bad idea. You can find my solution in the new revision of CustomButton script gist
